# Call a function on load using RiverPod and StateNotifiers

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I was following the [Resocoder tutorial](https://resocoder.com/2020/12/11/flutter-statenotifier-riverpod-tutorial-immutable-state-management) on how to manage states with RiverPod and StateNotifier.

What kind of trips me is as to how to call the `.getWeather` on an initial load with some let say default value. The example only illustrates using `context.read(..)` in the `onPressed(..)` function which is what is recommended in the riverpod docs.

But then how do you actually make a call on load, since that would mean calling `context.read` in the build method which is highly discouraged. (mentioned in the last part of this [section](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#contextreadmyprovider))

Comment: You can call your method in `didChangeDependencies` in `StateFullWidget` or `useeffect` if you are using hooks (RiverPod_hooks)

Comment: I did try the ```useeffect``` option but it gives some error and it rather feels like a side effect

Answer (score 5):

Because `.getWeather` is a Future function, you can actually add the future initialization inside the constructor of `WeatherNotifier` and let it update the state itself.

```
final weatherNotifierProvider = StateNotifierProvider(
  (ref) => WeatherNotifier(ref.watch(weatherRepositoryProvider)),
);


class WeatherNotifier extends StateNotifier<WeatherState> {
  final WeatherRepository _weatherRepository;

  WeatherNotifier(this._weatherRepository) : super(WeatherInitial()){
    getWeather('some city name'); // add here
  }

  Future<void> getWeather(String cityName) async {
    try {
      state = WeatherLoading();
      final weather = await _weatherRepository.fetchWeather(cityName);
      state = WeatherLoaded(weather);
    } on NetworkException {
      state = WeatherError("Couldn't fetch weather. Is the device online?");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this, but seems Whenever you create an instance of the WeatherNotifier class. The  initial state will always be modified by the getweather function immediately

Answer (score 0):

Look into `.family` modifier, you can pass data to a provider returned data/state.

https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/family

Listening to state with a parameter:

```
final state = ref.watch(myProvider('my arg'));
```

Creating a provider:

```
myProvider = StateNotifierProvider.family<String>((ref, arg) => "Hello $arg");
```

If you print state you'll get

```
print(state); //prints "Hello my arg"
```